# in Haskell, how do I derive: instance Category (Moore a b -> Moore b c)

Tags: haskell, instance, category-theory

I am trying to derive a Category instance for Moore automaton transformers, where:

```
data Moore a b = Moore b (a -> Moore a b)
type MooreT a b c = (Moore a b -> Moore a c)
```

The problem is, that `MooreT` has 3 parameters, whereas `Category` has only 2. I tried writing: `instance Category (MooreT a)`, but I didn't work.

The thing is, that the parameter `a` really doesn't matter for the definition of `id` and `(.)`. E.g:

```
id :: MooreT a b b
id x = x
```

Is there a way to define such an instance? Or do I have to define `MooreT` for a specific type `a`, like `type IntMooreT a b = MooreT Int a b`?

I am still new to Haskell, so I'm sorry, if this is a dumb question.

Comment: "I tried writing: `instance Category (MooreT a)`, but I didn't work". That's the correct way to do it. Please give the actual code you tried and the error message you encountered, and we can help you fix it

Comment: Here the error:
    * The type synonym `MooreT' should have 3 arguments, but has been given 1
    * In the instance declaration for `Category (MooreT a)'

Comment: @Reddog The compiler told you exactly what the problem was (you should read the errors it gives you) - `MooreT` is a type synonym, which means it must be fully applied when used (i.e., it mus be applied to 3 arguments) and in `instance Category (MooreT a)` it is clearly applied to only one.

Comment: @user2407038 Well, if it was fully applied, it would be missing the two free parameters it needs to be an instance of `Category`. I replied to Benjamin Hodgson, since he stated: "That's the correct way to do it". I **do** read the GHCI errors.

Comment: @Reddog Precisely, which is why you cannot typically make type synonyms into instances of type classes - you must wrap the type in a `newtype` or `data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MooreT a` is a `type` synonym for a subtype of `(->)`. `(->)` already has a `Category` instance, so `MooreT a` does too.

`ghci` can check to see if `MooreT`s already compose with `.`. Start with your definitions and the imports for `Category`, checking that we have the right `.` imported

```
Prelude> data Moore a b = Moore b (a -> Moore a b)
Prelude> type MooreT a b c = (Moore a b -> Moore a c)
Prelude> :t (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
Prelude> import Control.Category
Prelude Control.Category> import Prelude hiding ((.), id)
Control.Category Prelude> :t (.)
(.) :: Category cat => cat b c -> cat a b -> cat a c
```

Make a couple dummy `MooreT` values, `f` and `g`

```
Control.Category Prelude> data A = A
Control.Category Prelude> data B = B
Control.Category Prelude> data C = C
Control.Category Prelude> data D = D
Control.Category Prelude> f = undefined :: MooreT A B C
Control.Category Prelude> :t f
f :: MooreT A B C
Control.Category Prelude> g = undefined :: MooreT A C D
```

Check that composition works

```
Control.Category Prelude> :t g . f
g . f :: Moore A B -> Moore A D
```

Comment: Of course you are right! Couldn't see the forest for the trees :) Still wondering, however, why `instance Category (MooreT a) where ...` produces an error.